# Retrieve elements older than 5 minutes in DB

Tags: java

I'm using play framework version 1.2.5 and I would like to retrieve all the connected users that didn't update their session for 5 minutes, and then I would like to set their connection status to "disconnected".

Here is my model :

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Required
    public String name;

    public boolean isConnected;

    public Date lastConnectionDate;

}
```

And here is the Job that update the users :

```
Date fiveMinsAgo = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 5 * 60);
List<User> list = User.find("select u from User u where u.isConnected = true and u.lastConnectionDate < ?", fiveMinsAgo).fetch();

for (User user : list) {
    // We set these accounts as disconnected
    user.isConnected = false;
    user.save();
}
```

This code does not seem to work. User are set to "disconnected" even if their *lastConnectionDate* is not older than 5 minutes ago.
Did I do something wrong ?

Is there a better way/code to do what I would like to do ? (like an UPDATE command)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Date.getTime() returns milliseconds.

Try this:

```
Date fiveMinsAgo = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you both of you for your answers it solved my problem! I don't know what happened, I read the javadoc but I didn't see the unit was in ms. By the way, is my way of doing things correct? Or should I use an UPDATE query?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) time library. It avoids errors such as yours: `5 * 60` are 300 milliseconds. The time you are looking for would be something like `new DateTime().plusMinutes(-5)`.